# Configure maven to run app when gatling:test is triggered

Tags: maven, pom.xml, gatling

I always manually run the Spring boot application prior to running the `gatling:test` command so that the simulation's requests have a server to hit.

How to modify the pom.xml file so that the Spring Boot Application starts running before the simulation is run

Comment: I've got the same problem, maybe these posts will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053420/how-to-start-spring-boot-application-before-running-integration-test

Comment: Or have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986975/launch-spring-boot-app-before-gatling-simulation/44034610